# how to delete a word that has a dot in it in vim

Tags: vim

Currently if I have a word like this

```
bool t = someobject.someMethod() ;
```

If I want to delete

```
someobject.someMethod()
```

I do a `diw` on someobject and then `diw` on someMethod and then use the delete button to clear the rest. I wanted to know what would be the quickest way of deleting the entire word

```
 someobject.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you use uppercase to include special chars and it will delete until it reaches a white space:

dW

Comment: I'd like to add that `daW` will also delete the trailing space, which is useful if the word is surrounded by other words (with `diW`, you'd end up with two spaces between the remaining words).

Answer (score 5):

Do you really want to delete a word? I would imagine with that code snippet you probably want to *change* it instead. You have some options:

- `Bct(` change till the `(` symbol. (Note: May not need to use `B` to go to the beginning of the WORD)
- `BC` to change till the end of the line. There really not much to save. (`B` may not be needed)
- `c3iw` change 3 inner words. (Warning requires counting and to be on the first word)
- `ciW` change a WORD. Note: This changes the parenthesis as well, but that is a small price to pay.

If you really want to do a delete you can do similar command just replace the `c` with a `d` or `C` with `D`. Another option is to do `diw` And repeat the action twice via the `.` command.

Personally I prefer searching over counting so I tend to use `Bct(` to make the change. However each option has its usefulness depending on your needs.

For more help see:

```
:h word
:h WORD
:h c
:h C
:h t
:h B
:h iw
:h iW
:h .
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dot is at the end (last word in a sentence, or in programming when you want to remove a class/object name and the `.`), I use `df.`. An example I used five minutes ago:

```
return termcap.TermCap()
          ^
```

The `^` is the cursor's position.

- Press `B` (beginning of the word),
- `df.` (Delete Forward until and including `.`).

Result:

```
return TermCap()
       ^
```